# Polling not working in React JS mixin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, polling, ajax-polling

So I created the following mixin:

```
var Polling = {

    startPolling: function() {
        var self = this;

        setTimeout(function() {
            self.poll();

            if (!self.isMounted()) {
                return;
            }

            self._timer = setInterval(self.poll(), 15000);
        }, 1000);
    },

    poll: function() {
        if (!this.isMounted()) {
            return;
        }

        var self = this;
        console.log('hello');
        $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
            if (self.isMounted()) {
                self.setState({
                    error: false,
                    error_message: '',
                    users: result
                });
            }
        }).fail(function(response) {
            self.setState({
                error: true,
                error_message: response.statusText
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Note the `console.log('hello');` in the `poll` function. I should see this every 15 seconds according to this logic.

Now lets look at a react component:

```
//= require ../../mixins/common/polling.js
//= require ../../mixins/common/state_handler.js
//= require ../../components/recent_signups/user_list.js

var RecentSignups = React.createClass({

    mixins: [Polling, StateHandler],

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            users: null,
            error_message: '',
            error: false
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.startPolling();
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        if (this._timer) {
            clearInterval(this._timer);
            this._timer = null;
        }
    },

    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
        if (this.state.users         !== nextState.users ||
            this.state.error         !== nextState.error ||
            this.state.error_message !== nextState.error_message) {

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    },

    renderContents: function() {
        if (this.state.users === null) {
            return;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <UserList users={this.state.users} />
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
            {this.loading()}
            {this.errorMessage()}
            {this.renderContents()}
            </div>
        )
    }
});

RecentSignupsElement = document.getElementById("recent-signups");

if (RecentSignupsElement !== null) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <RecentSignups source={ "http://" + location.hostname + "/api/v1/recent-signups/" } />,
        RecentSignupsElement
    );
}
```

Here we see in the `componetDidMount` function I am calling `this.startPolling` When the page loads, what I see after 1 second is:

```
hello
hello
```

- **A)** its (`poll` fucntion) some how being called twice oO.
- **B)** its (`poll` function) never being called again.

The reason I separated polling out is so that I can use it in other components on the same page and not duplicate code.

Very simply question(s):

Why and how do I fix this? I need it to poll ever 15 seconds and I should only see `hello` once when `poll` is called the first time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On this line you call self.poll() and the result would be the timer:

```
self._timer = setInterval(self.poll(), 15000);
```

Instead pass the function:

```
self._timer = setInterval(self.poll, 15000);
```

Answer (score 0):

As another option, in the spirit of "you're code's not working? just use someone else's instead!", [react-async-poll](https://github.com/cameronbourke/react-async-poll/) is a handy component wrapper that you can use for polling.